# dropdown menu javascript not working on tablet or iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

My dropdown menu on my nav bar does not show up on iPhone 6 or iPad. However, the drop-down menu shows on my laptop (MacBook air) on chrome, safari, and firefox. My website is http://emilypedersen.me

The code for my navbar is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Emily Pedersen</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>

   </head>

  <body>
  <!-- .navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbarCollapse">
&#9776;
</button>
<a class = 'navbar-brand' href="home" id = 'brand'> <img src="images/emily_pedersen_2.jpg"></a>
<div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="mainNavbarCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-lg-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown">About &#x25BF;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="about_me">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="my_travels">My Travels</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Portfolio &#x25BF;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="resume">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="writings">Writings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<!-- /.navbar -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css for my nav bar:

```
@media (max-width: 62em) {
.navbar-nav {
padding-top: .425rem;
padding-left: 0.75rem;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
float: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
float: right;
}

#brand {
width:80%;
}

.navbar-toggler {
 width: 10%;
 }


.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav .nav-item {
 display: block;
 } 

.navbar-nav .nav-item + .nav-item {
 margin-left: 0;
 }

.dropdown-menu {
 position: relative;
 float: none;
 background-color: white;
 }

 .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  }
 }


.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
 color:white;
 }

.nav-link {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1em;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
 padding: 5px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 }

 .nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;

  }

 .nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:focus, .nav .open > a:hover {
   background-color: transparent;
  }

 .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
   background-color:transparent;
   color:#7EB6FF;
  }

  .dropdown-item {
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
   }

 .navbar-brand {
  margin-top:10px;
  }
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue of `@media` tags or the hardware on which my website is running. The drop-down menu works on desktop computers, laptops, and Android 7.0.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I checked in chrome browser with iphone5s specs in the dev tools, the nav bar works fine.Is there any other way to check it?

Comment: Thank you for checking! So you are able to see the dropdown menus under about and portfolio? When I used my dad's iphone and his iPad for some reason the dropdown menus were not showing when I clicked on about and portfolio.

Comment: Yeah.Welcome :) If you want to cross verify,you can check it either in chrome or firefox browser dev tools.I have sent out screen shot of your project in iphone  to your email id.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that this stackover answer: ([Bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown menu item not clickable on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510524/bootstrap-4-navbar-dropdown-menu-item-not-clickable-on-mobile-devices)).

Basically in my navigation.html I need to change from:

```
<a class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown">About &#x25BF;</a>
```

to:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About &#x25BF;</a>
```