# Bootstrap dropdown in fixed navbar doesn't react on tablet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, navbar, tablet

Sorry for bothering you guys, however the older posts (e.g. [Bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown menu item not clickable on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510524/bootstrap-4-navbar-dropdown-menu-item-not-clickable-on-mobile-devices)) do not do the job for me here. The given hints in that specific thread is already implemented in my code (see below).

I created a fixed navbar with **dropdown menus**. On desktop browser as well as mobile browsers on android phones all is splendid, however when it comes to tablet (also Android), the hamburger-menu unfolds but does not open any of those dropdown menus. Means: I can click the hamburger-menu, it opens, but the dropdown menus remain inactive and do not unfold on clicking.

You might try to duplicate the error by reducing the size of your browser, however this won't re-produce the error (as all is fine on desktop and mobile devices). Additionally: When I use the tablet horizontally, the breakingpoint is not reached for the hamburger-menu to show up. Then, curiously, all is fine and I can navigate through all dropdown menus.
I'm clueless here and like to show you the relevant code.

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.xxx.de">
                    <span class="brandicon icon-target"></span>
                    <span class="brandname">Brandname</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="btnicon icon-action-undo"></span>Früher<span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="link01.html">Antike</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link02.html">Mittelalter</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="btnicon icon-frame"></span>Heute<span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="otherlink1.html">Some name</a></li>
                                <li><a href="otherlink2.html">Rechtslage</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>               

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="btnicon icon-direction"></span>Another text<span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="linkage1.html">Header1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="linkage2.html">Header2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                                       


            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I am not to bootstrap and have so far not the slightest hint what I am missing here. All help will be appreciated greatly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All good - and sorry for bothering. I was actually able to reproduce the error on my desktop browser, I had my CSS messed up. Had some overflow problem which I could eliminate but changing my breakingpoint.